# Align photo position with css

Tags: css, image

My current project is a news portal. Some users are capable to put the news with some media related to it, like pictures. Currently, the CSS places the pictures in the right lower corner, after the text. I would like to put the photos in the right upper corner, around the text, like in this [example](http://www.omelete.com.br/musi/100017548/Casey_Affleck_vai_documentar_turne_de_rapper_de_Joaquin_Phoenix_.aspx). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The [CSS float property](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) is what you are looking for:

```
<div style="float:right">
  <img src="yourimage.jpg" />
  <p>Caption goes here...</p>
</div>
<div>
   The rest of your text goes here and
   will wrap around the image as in
   the example link you provided.
</div>
```